# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect one to many

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two tables (Ad) and (AdsImg) one Ad has many Images, I want to show only the first image from (AdsImg) with Ad list this is my code

```
userInfoModels = await (from a in _context.Ad.Take(5).OrderByDescending(a=> a.Date)
                     join s in _context.AdsImg.FirstOrDefault() on a.Id equals s.AdId 
                     
                    select new UserInfoModelView
                    {
                        Ad = a,
                        AdsImg = s

                    }).ToListAsync();
```

I'm getting this error "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Remove AdsImg.`FirstOrDefault()`** or only have first record to join

```
userInfoModel = await (from a in _context.Ad.Take(5).OrderByDescending(a=> a.Date)
                     join s in _context.AdsImg on a.Id equals s.AdId 
                     select new UserInfoModelView
                     {
                        Ad = a,
                        AdsImg = s

                     }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**2. Change `ListAsync()` to `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`**

Add `FirstOrDefaultAsync` here and you will get the first record after join.

All tested and works.